# Possibly undefined when using a condition on computed object property against static property

Tags: typescript

I have an object which is defined by the following types:

```
const exchange = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
type Exchange = typeof exchange[number];

export type Obj = Partial<Record<Exchange, BarItem>>;

type BarItem = {
  ask: string;
  bid: string;
};

const obj: Obj = {};
```

Now let's say I have a function which operates on the `obj` variable:

```
function test(exchange: Exchange) {
  if (obj[exchange]) {
    // ERROR: object is possibly 'undefined'
    obj[exchange].ask = "";
  }

  const a = obj[exchange];
  if (a) {
    // works fine
    a.ask = "";
  }
}
```

Why is it that when checking with a static variable works as expected, meanwhile checking with the object with a dynamic variable does not work? The exchange parameter cannot change... why does typescript thinks that way?

Comment: TypeScript is not guaranteed that `obj[exchange]` doesn't change before you attempt to use it. Storing it in a variable lets TypeScript monitor its usage more easily and lets it narrow types.

Answer (score 0):

type `Obj` has the following type:

```
type Obj = {
    a?: BarItem | undefined;
    b?: BarItem | undefined;
    c?: BarItem | undefined;
}
```

It seems the compiler isn't able to deduce that this is a safe operation, probably because it doesn't understand that `exchange` never changes in value. Since you know that the operation is safe you can use the `!` bang operator which removes the nullable type from the left operand.

```
obj[exchange]!.ask = "";
```

Alternatively, inside the if block you can also recast `obj` as non-partial with

```
type Concrete<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]-?: Type[Property];
};
```